# jquery text with image rotation

Tags: jquery, image, text, scroller

How can i rotate an image with some associated text in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

(No JQuery but ) there is a css selector named "**transform**" that  performing this kind of rotation. For example see: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

Comment: Note that whilst the transform property is definitely awesome, it is a css3 property and doesn't work in IE.  There's a surprise...